# Fixing the viewpoint of map

Tags: c#, arcgis

I am working with ArcGIS sdk for .net. Whenever the user clicks the + or - key or double clicks the map view it zooms in/zooms out. I want to ensure that when above events occur the map only changes the view to a certain level and not beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Controls_MapView.htm)'s [`MinScale`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Controls_MapView_MinScale.htm), [`MaxScale`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Controls_MapView_MaxScale.htm), and [`MaximumExtent`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Controls_MapView_MaximumExtent.htm) properties.

Comment: It worked perfectly but only when i put it in the Spatial Reference Changed event handler